# Uploading image to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, koa

I am uploading a single image (upload.single('file') is Multer middleware.), Koa framework for nodeJs. Everything works on localhost but not on the prod environment. Here is the the path for the prod environment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh5xS.png)

Prod env: **Cliet-> Api gateway-> NLB -> service to S3 bucket.**

localhost env: **Cliet-> service to S3 bucket.**

The problem is the size of the image increased when it reaches to service before uploading to S3 bucket and it will be distorted image (237kb increases to 418kb). But using localhost all works fine. I used postman as a client for uploading image.

```
async create(ctx: Context, values: any): Promise<any> {

    // The image size increased before sending to S3 bucket
    console.log('REQUEST----', values.file)

    const params = {
      Bucket: env.Bucket,
      Key: `images/${values.file.originalname}`,
      Body: values.file.buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: values.file.mimetype,
      ContentLength: values.file.size,
    }


    try {
      const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    } catch(e) {
         ctx.throw(HttpStatusCodes.InternalServerError, {
          message: `Something went wrong when updating advertisement` + e,
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Befkadu,
I have some questions to get a better understanding of your question:  
What error are you receiving? http 500? 
Have you checked your cloudwatch events? 
Please add your security AIM configs and Access Control List(ACL) for S3.

Comment: Hi @RafaelGorski thanks for your reply. I got no errors, the image is actually deployed but distorted. The problem is appeared in the service  before sending the image to S3 **Cliet-> Api custom gateway-> NLB -> service -> S3 bucket**., the image size changed(only on prod env).  It works fine on localhost env. My console log is written in my service before sending to S3. 
IAM - AmazonS3FullAccess
ACLs settings - All settings false

Comment: When you say "api custom gateway" you mean AWS API Gateway ( https://aws.amazon.com/pt/api-gateway/ ) ? If so are you trying to use the following approach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html  ?  Did you try to test your API Gateway method using the API Gateway Web Interface -> Method Test? Can you edit your question with the before and after result with the extra chars/bytes added to your image?

Comment: Can you tell me the format to test the image in the Request body of Method Test?
```{
  "file": {
    "name": "37227489_1914616801893633_7617884751617064960_n.jpg",
 "size": 497676,
 "type": "image/jpeg",
 "webkitRelativePath": ""
  }
}```

Comment: you may check the raw bytes Base64 encoding to copy and past there. example: W3JhdyBieXRlc10=